# why i can get the ICMP ECHO REPLY?(my ping program with winpcap)

Tags: c++, ip, ping, icmp, winpcap

I don't know why i can get the icmp echo reply.
[ICMP ECHO Resquest message that i write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg6DA.png)

[ICMP ECHO Resquest message that window icmp echo request function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjvgB.png)

Also my ICMP Message don't pass router. I do not why this happen.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  At which host were the captures made? How do you know it's not passing some router?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I solve this problem. problem's cause was worng IP Checksum.